# Automorphism in Z7

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

how many automorphisms are there in  Z7?

Z7={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
 Identity and inverse are two automorphisms I found.

Comment: Hint: What does an automorphism mean? You're mapping elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to elements in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, with the map being invertible, right?
What group do you know that fits this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\text{Aut }\mathbb Z_7\simeq U_7=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$ So there are $6$ such automorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the automorphism is completely determined by where the generator is mapped to. Let's say you have an automorphism that maps $1\mapsto n$. Which values of $n$ does this work for? That is how many automorphisms you have.

Clearly this won't work if $n=0$, because then everything would get mapped to $0$ and you would no longer have an automorphism. However, I maintain that $n$ can be any other element of $Z_7$. This is because $7$ is a prime number so $1,2,3,4,5,$ and 6 are all generators of $Z_7$. I leave the details of why this is true up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Generator needs to be taken to generator. Your automorphism is completely determined where $[1]$ goes. What are your generators?